# Was "Rosebud" a real brand of sled?

Tags: citizen-kane

In the film "Citizen Kane" young Kane owns a sled with the name "Rosebud". I have always assumed that the name was invented for the film, but I was recently reading "A Tree Grows in Brooklyn" (by Betty Smith) and came across this text:

> And the sleds! (Or, as the Williamsburg children called them, the
> sleighs.) There was a child's  dream of heaven come true! A new sled
> with a flower someone had dreamed up painted on it-a  deep blue flower
> with bright green leaves-the ebony-black painted runners, the smooth
> steering  bar made of hard wood and gleaming varnish over All! And the
> names painted on them!  "Rosebud!" "Magnolia!" "Snow King!" "The
> Flyer!" Thought Francie, "If I could only have one of  those, I'd
> never ask God for another thing as long as I live."

The film "Citizen Kane" was released in September 1941 while "A Tree Grows in Brooklyn" was published in 1943 so it is certainly possible that Betty Smith took the Rosebud name from the film but I was wondering if perhaps "Rosebud" was a *real* sled brand (or model).

Does anyone have any evidence either way?

Comment: Not a brand but rather a "type" I suspect. Not a brand like say Ford but a model like Mustang

Comment: A web search suggests it’s unlikely

Comment: Feels like a bit of DIY tole painting, like painting a name on your boat. I'm pretty sure most people would be making their own sleds, not buying them. A bit of individual touch on the paint job would be part & parcel.

Comment: @Tetsujin according to Welles: "_Rosebud_ is the trade name of a cheap little sled". See linked question.

Comment: @OrangeDog - it was a movie prop owned by the *character*. That doesn't make it "real".

Comment: @Tetsujin no, but it makes it an brand/model name, not a DIY name

Answer (score 2):

Rosebud was not a real sled.  In fact, the author of Citizen Kane, Herman Mankiewicz, wrote this semi-autobiographical film based on a bike of his which was stolen, so Rosebud was actually a bicycle.  Supposedly, and we will never know the truth behind this, Mankiewicz went to a horse track in 1914 and won; the horse he put the bet on was [Old Rosebud](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/who-really-wrote-citizen-kane-180958782/).  I believe *after* the movie came out, someone manufactured sleds using the name Rosebud, as there are clearly pics of sleds with that inscribed on them.